# how to devide two counted values with different conditions Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to make somthing like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(is_available = 1) / COUNT(*) FROM users;
```

but the condition of is_available = 1 doesn't reflect 
it always gives result of "1"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`. For example:

```
select
  sum(case when is_available = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
  /
  count(*) 
from users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `is_available` just takes two values, `0` and `1`, you can use:

```
SELECT AVG(is_available)
FROM users;
```

If it can take other non-NULL values:

```
SELECT AVG(is_available = 1)
FROM users;
```

And, if you really need to counts `NULL`s, then you can use `COALESCE()` or:

```
SELECT SUM(is_available = 1) / COUNT(*)
FROM users;
```